# Php file/script isn’t called

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to fetch some data with an $.getJSON call.
But when I load the page the corresponding php file isn’t called. Nothing is loaded in the console section and in the network section in the browsers ( Chrome ) debugger.

This is the code from the vue file:

```
<script>
import jQuery from 'jquery'
let $ = jQuery;

export default {
    name: 'Formular1',

    data: function () {
        return {
            datas: [],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        lade_daten: function () {
            let vm = this;
            $.getJSON("/api/call_evm.php", function(result){
                vm.datas = result;
                console.log(vm.datas);
            });
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        this.lade_daten();
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost/evm-formular/api',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api': ''
            }
        }
    } 
},
runtimeCompiler: true,
configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
},
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.externals({
        jquery: 'jQuery',
        select2:'select2'
    })
}
}
```

Is this a vue or a php problem?
I am completely puzzled.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well if you don’t see this causing any request at all in the browser dev tools network panel, then it can hardly be a PHP problem …

Comment: Learn to use the Chrome developer tools, they are pretty spectacular.  You can load your script files in the developer tools, and step through them, to see what may be happening / not happening.  See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: I think it is overkill to import the entire jquery just so you can do REST requests. Most of jquery will be useless to you if you are using vue. I suggest you look up axios: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm considering it.